# "Type name already in use" error when deploy to org

Tags: apex, deployment

When I'm trying to deploy my class from one sandbox to another via Copado I'm getting "Type name already in use: {myClassName}" error. Error is throwing in Test class.
It points class and inner class names rows.
I guess it is not an issue with Copado. Any suggestions?

```
public class MyClass { //row where error is throwing in test class 
    //some code goes here

    public class MyInnerClass {//row where error is throwing in test class
        //some code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably deploying a .cls file with `public class MyClass` into an org as a New file but that org already has a different .cls file that is defined with `public class MyName`

Comment: @cropredy No I've checked and it is a new one. In your case, it had to overwrite then